# Sending build artifacts over ssh is very slow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to jenkins . I am trying to deploy php codes to  production server via "Publish over ssh" plugin . I enabled it in "post-build actions". Everything is fine but transfer is too slow [ 2 hours for 40MB transfer]
Here is the scenario:

> > 1. Entire project is setup in local.Total size is nearly 700MB.
> > 2. All codes pushed to BitBucket.
> > 3. Now i configured build in Jenkins with "Send build artifacts over ssh " as post-build option.Inside transfer set i added " **/*. * " for source file option .
> > 4. It is taking hours and hours to transfer entire project . Within 2 hours it transferred only 140MB.

Is it normal ? Do i need to change any settings? Network connections between  the server in which Jenkins runs and the production server is fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"rsync over ssh "  solved the problem of code transfer to production server.Now its taking only 2-3 seconds for a build.

Comment: Rsync will be faster AFTER the first time as it does not copy everything, only files changed, added or deleted since last rsync. Delete the target and it'll be slow again. Just a transient improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 2 hours for 40MB is unexpectedly slow. However, it is not uncommon to get abysmally slow archiving of artifacts from agent to master.

Below are links to the 2 open tickets I know of tracking this. There are many others reported that have been closed over the last decade, but in my environment, I'm getting ~13Mbps transfers, despite the 10Gbps links we have between all nodes in our Jenkins cluster.

[JENKINS-18276](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18276)

[JENKINS-63517](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63517)

Comment: I ended up writing a groovy function that accepts a job/project name, a file glob pattern, and a target directory, looks up the path to the last successful build of the specified project on the controller (where the artifacts are stored) and scps them (using the specified file glob pattern) to the target dir. Works great, and about 13x faster than copyArtifacts in my infrastructure. I called it fastCopyArtifacts.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly related to your question of sending artifacts via SSH, but it may help others who come upon this while trying to reduce the time it takes to archive artifacts in general.  I used the [pipeline utility plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file) to zip everything I wanted to archive into a zip file, then I unzipped it when I want to [un-archive](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/) it later.

That reduced the time by about 50x for me, presumably because it was just 1 file to transfer/archive/unarchive instead of a bunch of small files, and zipping/unzipping was less that 1 second in my case--much less time than archiving the individual files separately.

```
zip zipFile: 'artifacts.zip'
archiveArtifacts 'artifacts.zip'
```

then

```
copyArtifacts(filter: '**/*', projectName: currentBuild.projectName, selector: specific(params.archived_build_number))
unzip zipFile: 'artifacts.zip', quiet: true
```

The zip function also has a parameter to archive the zip, but I showed it separately here to be explicit. Again, nothing about this is specific to your SSH scenario, but I thought it would be useful to post it anyway.